# Build library files into build folder with yarn workspaces and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarnpkg

I created a yarn workspace alongside typescript as such.
I have three folders with their own `package.json`

```
/api
/client
/lib
```

The point is to share code from lib between API and client. In an API file for example I can do

```
import {User, UserAccount} from '@myproject/lib'
```

There are problems with this.

1. I need to build `lib` each time I change something
2. `/api`'s `build` files point to `C:/myproject/lib/build/index.js`

Since I would like to deploy the project to heroku by just pushing what's in `/api/build`, this will fail because it can't find the files in `/lib/build`. Maybe I can push both build folders up to heroku, but what I was hoping for was some magic that compiled all `/lib/src` files into `/api/build`. My `/client` is running in expo which I assume uses something like webpack or I don't know what, and it seems to do this. Do I need to use webpack to acheive this or can I do it with yarn workspaces and typescript?

Answer (score 2):

In `tsconfig.json` of `client` and `api` packages you need two configs, if you don't already have them:

1. In `"compilerOptions"` make sure you have `"composite": true`
2. Add `"references": [{ "path": "relativePathTo/lib" }]`

When you run tsc, run it with the --build (-b) flag, like this: `tsc -b`. This will build the active package and any package in `references`. More on TypeScript [Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html).

This fixes your problem in development. Depending on your project configuration, you may need to do more things to put it through the CI.